# MySQL: Keeping a "changed" flag

Tags: mysql

My application tries to sync database entries between multiple independent servers.
Therefore, I need to know which entries have been added or modified since the last sync. My idea is to add a (BIT-) column to each table that has to be synced which indicates if the row has changed. The default value would be 1, so that newly inserted rows are marked as new. On every UPDATE, the "changed" flag should be automatically set to 1. After I sync, I would like to reset the flag to 0 manually.
I don't want to update the "changed" flag manually because there are a lot of places where rows can be inserted or updated. I have looked into triggers but as far as I understood, there is no way to get the rows that have been changed without doing something like

```
IF NEW.col_1 <> OLD.col_1 OR NEW.col_2 <> OLD.col_2 ...
```

I would like to avoid this because the database structure is likely to change.
I know that you can have a timestamp column that is updated on every UPDATE, but can you have someting similar with other data types?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html).

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).
>   Replication is asynchronous by default - slaves need not to connected
>   permanently to receive updates from the master. This means that
>   updates can occur over long-distance connections and even over
>   temporary or intermittent connections such as a dial-up service.
>   Depending on the configuration, you can replicate all databases,
>   selected databases, or even selected tables within a database.

An advantage to this, if that MySQL itself handles the replication, so you don't need to write the code to handle synchronization. It is also relatively easy to add additional slaves to the replication cluster.

MySQL has a nice description of how to set up [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-howto.html).

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I need. First of all, the database servers cannot access each other directly because they are behind firewalls of different schools and I can't get the admins to open their ports to each other. Second, I don't want to replicate all the data in a table but only a specific subset of rows. And third, I need to remap the IDs of my entities as they don't have the same IDs on all servers. The servers are at this moment independent from each other but should exchange _some_ data in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

You can start fiddling with triggers to do what you want.  However, setting and unsetting the flag seems disquieting.  I assume that you have already looked into solutions such as MySQL Replication (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)) that provide this functionality.

I would suggest adding a `ModifiedAt` timestamp to each table.  In the more recent versions of MySQL, this doesn't even require a trigger (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)).  Then, your replication process would do the following:

1. Loop through each table and fetch the maximum `ModifiedAt` timestamp for each table.
2. Fetch all the records from the table that are between the previous `ModifiedAt` and the new one.
3. Do whatever you want to do with those records.
4. Record the `ModifiedAt` for each table.

This should ensure that updates are handled correctly for the replication.  As a bonus, each record will also keep track of the last time it was changed.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am already using. However, due to some complicated circumstances (with which I don't want to bore you), this might not be enough. It's something like this: Server A provides data, Server B fetches some of them, Server C fetches something else. Some data is fetched by both B and C. And there is some data that changes today on Server A but cannot be fetched by Server B until its admin says so. I think I'll have to figure this out by myself.